# How to change docker container's source code without restarting it?

Tags: docker

I have an application where I am using two docker containers. Say container **A** and **B**. Now B is dependent upon A. So when I start container 'B', I do mention the ip address of container 'A' in the command line.

Now I have a code change in the container 'A'. If I have to restart the container 'A' after change the source code then after restarting A's ip address will change. For that reason container 'B' will lose connection to 'A' and I have to restart 'B' with new ip address of 'A'.

Is there any docker approach where I can reserve the ip address for container 'A' always? or can I make the code changes without restarting the container 'A'?
Please suggest.

Comment: What version of docker are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a service discovery like **[consul](https://www.consul.io/)**, combined with **[registrator](https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator)** in order to record `A` (in consul) each time it starts.

Then `B` could query consul in order to get `A` up-to-date IP address.

See "[Automatic Docker Service Announcement with Registrator](http://progrium.com/blog/2014/09/10/automatic-docker-service-announcement-with-registrator/)"

If your containers are not managed by the same docker daemon (meaning you are in a multi-hosts multi-nodes environment), you would use **[docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/)** (still in conjunction with `consul`):

- "[Deploying Containers with Docker Swarm and Docker Networking](http://technologyconversations.com/2015/11/25/deploying-containers-with-docker-swarm-and-docker-networking/)"
- "[Atlassian Orchestration with Docker: multi-host support for the win!](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/12/atlassian-docker-orchestration/)"

Comment: Hmm, can't this just be done with the new networking in 1.9?

Comment: @AdrianMouat not without a discovery service, from what I have seen.

Comment: Well you can't run overlay without etcd/consul. But I don't think you need registrator. I'm not sure why you put Swarm in the mix; it doesn't really say anything about networking.

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure it's a lot simpler in 1.9. If I find time, I'll add an answer (not that yours is wrong, it's just that I think it's overkill for the q).

Comment: @adr great, I will look forward to read and test your answer. Will it work in a multi-node environment?

Comment: For a single host, the new networking makes containers addressable by name, or they're on the same network (only for custom networks); `docker network create foo`, then `docker run --net=foo --name=conta foo`, `docker run --net=foo --name=contb foo` and both containers can reach each other by `conta`/`contb` https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/

Comment: @thaJeztah that doc also includes "Docker does not support automatic service discovery on the default bridge network. If you want to communicate with container names in this default bridge network, you must connect the containers via the legacy docker run --link option.". Hence my answer.

Comment: @VonC yes, it's disabled for the default bridge to keep the "old" behavior as a default, but creating a custom bridge network is probably a lot simpler for a simple case, then to add consul, registrator

Answer (score 1):

Two ways

### Custom IP's

You can customise Docker networking inside a container far beyond what Docker allows on the command line with [`pipework` by Jérôme Petazzoni](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework).

It allows you to set the networking you would like so you could create a bridge, lets be inventive and call it `br1`, for your containers and set specific IP's on each container or even use a dhcp server to allocate the IP's. This is a static config:

Start the `aa` container and add an IP on our bridge, `br1` as `eth0`

```
→ docker run -d --net=none --name aa busybox cat
→ pipework br1 -eth0 aa 192.168.17.4/24
```

Start the `bb` container and add 192.168.17.5 on br1

```
→ docker run -d --net=none --name bb busybox cat
→ pipework br1 -eth0 bb 192.168.17.5/24
```

Now we know IP address of a container all the time

```
→ docker exec bb ping 192.168.17.4
```

### Docker hosts file

Docker 1.8 enabled `/etc/hosts` container name sharing by default.

Docker 1.9 disabled this on the default network/bridge `docker0` but will share container name information on a custom network

Create the network

```
→ docker create network shared
ce8fb4c6d6d379e87314952f4dfbcdcd6cf6c03416431721bb8f6001492575ea
```

Run a container named `aa`

```
→ docker run --name aa --net=shared -ti -d busybox sleep 5
754c7716cee65526cb2284066ccf2e495d494f5c351e281a89672aa5bdf1d84d
```

Ping by container name `aa`

```
→ docker run --name bb --net=shared -ti --rm busybox ping aa
PING aa (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.354 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.081 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.090 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.114 ms

--- aa ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 50% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.081/0.409/1.354 ms
```

Now the container has stopped after 5 seconds

```
→ docker run --name bb --net=shared -ti --rm busybox ping aa
ping: bad address 'aa'
```

### Docker multi node hosts file

Docker natively supports multiple host networking via its [`overlay` network driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/). This does require an external service discovery agent to provide the kay/value store service but it means you can do this over multiple docker nodes too.

Answer (score -1):

you do this with the `--volumes-from` flag. It would look like this:

```
$ docker run a --name a
$ docker run b --name b --volumes-from a
```

Docker will transparently handle the networking for you.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/